# Change basemap urls in Esri ArcGIS 4.3 to begin with https:// instead of file://

Tags: android, cordova, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

I'm building a cordova application with the Esri ArcGIS JS 4.3  and I have a problem with basemap urls.

They are defined as: `//services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer` and  when my Android application requests the resource it is translated into `file://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer`.

How can I change `file://` into `https://` so that the request is valid?

Answer (score 1):

Well, As I can see here you are expecting `secured(https)` url in your project.

In your case you can convert your url as mentioned below-

Earlier Link-

[//services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer](http:////services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer)

New basemap url-

https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer

technically both urls are same and it will work as expected.

Hoping this will help you:)